# gcp pub/sub push endpoint with key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to route logs from gcp to pub/sub, but the endpoint I need to send the logs to requires a license key in the header of the JSON body in order to accest the POST request. How can I be able to add a header to the JSON body getting routed with logs? Or how can I add this key to the push endpoint screen?[image]

Comment: My best guess is that instead of defining a push subscription, you define a Cloud Function or Cloud Run to be invoked when a message is published to the topic.  This would receive the notification and payload and be code under your control.  From there, you could then perform a REST POST operation to your actual target endpoint adding what ever headers or reformatting you desire.  Similar stories may be able to be achieved if you have Cloud Endpoints or Apigee is proxies.

Comment: Ok understood..thank you

Comment: Subscriptions do not add data. Subscription direct how messages are delivered to subscribers. You will need to add your custom headers in the data being sent to Pub/Sub messages. For details on what you can do, read this link: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push

Comment: @John Hanley could you please create an answer based on your comment, since you provided the correct way for above scenario? Thanks!

Comment: @JohnHanley - Oooh ... can you define a subscription to include arbitrary HTTP headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer was provided by @John Hanley in the comment section:

> Subscriptions do not add data. Subscription direct how messages are
>   delivered to subscribers. You will need to add your custom headers in
>   the data being sent to Pub/Sub messages. For details on what you can
>   do, read this [link](http://www.cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push).

Answer (score 0):

At this point in time it is not possible to include custom (Authorization) headers in a pub/sub push subscription. (1) You either use an endpoint within GCP to send your pub/sub messages to, which makes use of GCP as an authentication provider. (2) The other option (not recommended at all) is to use an API key in the url and send it to an endpoint of your choice.

(1) You can make use of other GCP services like cloud functions or cloud run to forward pub/sub messages. Create a new request with the appropriate headers and pass on the message to another endpoint. The downside of this approach is that compute costs may spin out of control, since you fire up a cloud function or cloud run instance every time a single message passes through.

You could consider to write a cloud function in Golang to increase the speed. On the other hand, cloud build can handle up to 80 concurrent requests per instance. Someone

(2) Although I still see it very often, using API keys is bad practice. API keys have no expiration, so when they are stolen, someone can access your API indefinitely. That's why Bearer tokens exists with a limited lifetime.

Neither options are perfect, but I would write a small footprint cloud function in Golang to pass on messages to the endpoint of your choice.